# Почему WaitAll не работает должным образом

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

```
private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    _timer.Stop();
    _logic.AddLogToMainFileServerLogs("*********Метод распределения запущен из таймера.*********");

    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var depot in _logic.Depots)
    {
        _logic.AddLogToMainFileServerLogs("*********РЦ " + depot.Code + " запущено в поток.*********");

        Task task = Task.Run(() => _logic.DistributeTrucks(depot.Code));
        tasks.Add(task);
        //_= await _logic.DistributeTrucks(depot.Code);
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

    _logic.AddLogToMainFileServerLogs("*********Метод распределения из таймера отработал РЦ.*********");

    _timer.Start();
}
```

Я хочу что бы метод `DistributeTrucks` выполнялся параллельно, но при этом запуск таймера должен происходить только тогда, когда все задачи выполняться.
Сейчас я вижу в логах следующее:

1. *********Метод распределения запущен из таймера.*********
2. *********РЦ 1 запущено в поток.*********
3. *********РЦ 2 запущено в поток.*********
4. *********РЦ 3 запущено в поток.*********
5. *********Метод распределения из таймера отработал РЦ.*********
6. Выполнения методов

А хочу видеть:

1. *********Метод распределения запущен из таймера.*********
2. *********РЦ 1 запущено в поток.*********
3. *********РЦ 2 запущено в поток.*********
4. *********РЦ 3 запущено в поток.*********
5. Выполнение методов
6. *********Метод распределения из таймера отработал РЦ.*********

Что не так делаю?

```
 public async void DistributeTrucks(string depotCode)
```

Comment: Не вдаваясь в подробности: `public async Task DistributeTrucks(string depotCode)` и `Task task = Task.Run(async () => await _logic.DistributeTrucks(depot.Code));` вас спасут. При чем можно даже лучше так попробовать в строке с таской `Task task = _logic.DistributeTrucks(depot.Code)`.

Comment: [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async) - обязательно прочитайте эту статью, лучше на английском если можете, перевод кривоват.

Comment: Что за метод `logic.DistributeTrucks(depot.Code))`?

Comment: @aepot, спасибо за Ваш комментрий. Вообще, сколько про это читаю - столько раз прихожу к выводу, что асинхронное прогрммировние - совершенно сворачивающее мозг. Это смешение императивного и деклартивного подхода... с тредами куда как проще.

Comment: @tym32167 здесь по сигнатуре метода все понятно. :)

Comment: @S.H. Когда разберётесь с `async/await`, забудете про треды как про страшный сон

Comment: @aepot вторая замена необязательна. А вот избавляться от `Task.Run` в UI-потоке как раз не лучшая идея...

Comment: @S.H. нет там декларативного подхода. Кстати, если желаете "по-сворачивать мозг" дальше - посмотрите Reactive Extensions (RX)

Comment: @PavelMayorov стоп-стоп, `Task.Run` нужен только для CPU-Bound операций. А для I/O операций, какая разница, в каком потоке будет выполняться колбэк (продолжение метода после `await`)? Быть может там в колбэке вообще требуется восстановление контекста и работа с UI? Я бы не был столь категоричен на вашем месте. _Спавн потоков без причины - признак дурачины_ :) Поэтому пусть автор решает, как ему удобнее, я предложил 2 варианта, и без детального разбора, что там внутри асинхронного метода, мне неизвестно, какой из вариантов лучше, и именно поэтому я скинул ссылку на статью вторым комментарием.

Comment: @PavelMayorov [прикольный асинхронный пример RX.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62616291/12888024)

Comment: @aepot там разница в том, что планировщик пула потоков работает быстрее, чем очередь сообщений WINAPI с двойным маршаллингом

Comment: @PavelMayorov верно, но я не вижу здесь предпосылок для реюза потоков из пула. Здесь нет семафора, который ограничивает уровень параллельности. А следовательно спавн +100500 новых потоков будет кушать проц неоправданно сильно. А вот с повторного запуска этой процедуры возможно эффективность станет примерно одинаковая, потому что пойдет реюз из пула. Я не спорю, если что, но здесь важен контекст и возможно результаты тестов, и еще понимание, насколько это место в коде требует производительности, и если не требует, то совершенно все равно, каким из способов оно будет сделано.

Comment: @aepot не будет тут +100500 новых потоков, это же пул

Comment: @PavelMayorov вы же можете представить себе ситуацию, когда при выполнении этого кода - будет спавн большого числа потоков. Зачем тогда вы говорите наверняка, что не будет?

Comment: @aepot проверил, ваш вариант работает, дайте ответ, я приму его. Еще подскажите, в данном случае, метод `DistributeTrucks` будет работать параллельно, правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async void` технтчески невозможно ожидать, но возможно `async Task`.

```cs
public async Task DistributeTrucks(string depotCode)
```

Тогда строчку с таской можно поменять вот так

```cs
Task task = _logic.DistributeTrucks(depot.Code);
```

> Еще подскажите, в данном случае, метод `DistributeTrucks` будет работать параллельно, правильно?

Технически это работает так: когда в внутри метода встречается первый `await`, асинхронная машина состояний позвращает ожидающий завершения метода `Task` в точку вызова. Код, размещенный до первого `await` будет выполнен синхронно как в самом обычном синхронном метода (уделяйте этому внииание при написании асинхронных методов, иначе можете ропасть в ситуацию, когда асинхронный метод блокирует вызывающий поток на некоторое время). То есть в этот момент  переменная `task` будет добавлена в список и цикл продолжит выполение.

Следовательно одновременно может выполняться (ожидаться) несколько или даже много асинхронных ожиданий. Можно сказать, что это параллельно, да. Но технически это не так. Вы просто ожидаете список тасок `WaitAll`, которые внутри себя тоже что-то ждут, ну там где у вас `await` внутри метода `DistributeTrucks`, при ожидании код не выполняется, этим и отличается асинхронность от параллельности. По сути, можно выполнять одновременно кучу асинхронных вызовов, технически используя для выполнения кода всего один поток. А когда есть всего один поток, то о какой параллельности может быть речь, верно?

Говоря самым простым языком `Thread` поток - это выполнялка, а `Task` - это ожидалка. При том, ожидалка может ждать и завершения выполнения кода в отдельном потоке текущего приложения `await Task.Run`, и выполнения какой-то операции вне текущего компьютера, например ожидать ответа из сети `await httpClient.GetStringAsync()`. Во втором случае код выполняется на сервере, а вы просто ждете результат.